# Do I need to fully update 12.10 before upgrading to 13.04? (Non-internet USB upgrade)

Tags: installation, upgrade, live-usb, software-updater

I'm wondering if I need to install all updates on 12.10 before I upgrade to 13.04. I'm not using the update manager to upgrade, but I'm using a USB stick instead. I've always liked the way that way of upgrading turned out vs the internal internet upgrade system. Also, my packages/software sources are broken preventing me from updating. Can I still use a USB stick to safely upgrade? Or does my current install need to be in working order?

I don't need help fixing my current install; I just don't want to do work all that work fixing it if I don't have to.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately the offline upgrade path using an USB installation CD was discontinued and does not work for 13.04 any more. You will not be able to upgrade without a functional Internet connection.

> Offline upgrade options via alternate CDs are no longer offered for Ubuntu Desktop and Ubuntu Server. Please ensure you have network connectivity to one of the official mirrors or to a locally accessible mirror and follow the instructions above. <sup>[Raring Ringail Release Notes](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/RaringRingtail/ReleaseNotes)</sup>

Also see: [How can I perform an offline upgrade using Ubiquity on the installation disc?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/283026/offline-upgrade-from-ubuntu-12-10-to-13-04-using-the-installation-disk)

Many packages may be upgraded from the CD/USB installation medium but some may not. This is even more an issue when you hold many broken packages.

We can not recommend you upgrade from an incomplete or malfunctioning system. The safest way to go now for you would be performing a clean installation of 13.04. Make extra sure to keep your HOME untouched when you do so.

> [**As always it is strongly recommended to backup your data before you perfom a release upgrade.**](https://askubuntu.com/questions/2596/comparison-of-backup-tools)

Comment: So the listed upgrade feature in the installer no longer works? I'm using the standard x64 live installer.

Comment: It only works when you are connected to the Internet, and it will upgrade with additionally downloaded packages.