# how can I update ubuntu v12.04 to v13.04 without using a internet connection?

Tags: updates

I have ubuntu 12.04 and I want to update to 13.04, but without downloading it from the website. How can I do it ?

Comment: Why akk the downvotes?. It is a interesting question, and it is not answered in the possible duplicate.

Comment: @JavierRivera It does not list any research effort. It also contains a requirement which is not elaborated upon. Why would one want to upgrade with the requirement of not having to download something? Either you have to download a CD/DVD image (web page), or you'll have to upgrade using newer repositories (APT downloads over HTTP as well).

Comment: Everybody is free to have their own reason to downvote question, but I feel poor research is a bad one. If the question can be interesting and useful for a bunch of people I feel that it should be upvoted to have better chances of getting a good answer. A personal question, that applies mostly only to the poster is a different thing, IMO.

Comment: the dupe shows how to upgrade using update manager, which technically doesn't involve downloading an iso and burning it to disc. as noted previously, the question is a bit unclear and shows no research effort.

Comment: You'll have to upgrade with a LiveCD, which the dupe covers.

Answer (score 1):

13.04 Isn't an LTS so Canonical doesn't make a disk for it.  Canonical typically makes install media available for their LTS (long term support) OS editions.  The current LTS is 12.04.

When install media is available, it can be purchased here:
http://shop.canonical.com/index.php?cPath=17

Comment: Unfortunately, install media for 13.04 still require you have an active internet connection to be able to upgrade an existing installation. See http://askubuntu.com/q/283026/88802. *"So here the answer: even when using the Ubuntu installation disc, one cannot upgrade the a newer version of Ubuntu without Internet connection. Ubiquity needs to have an Internet connection in order to make the upgrade option selectable."*

Answer (score 0):

It's not clear if you do not want to download an iso and burn to disk, or if you just have no internet and don't want to download anything. I'm guessing the first case...and your existing system is updated this way...

**For Ubuntu Desktop**:

- Simply start the Update Manager and follow the on-screen instructions.
- Or use the Ubuntu Server instructions below.

**For Ubuntu Server**:

- Install the *update-manager-core* package if it is not already installed:

  > $ sudo apt-get install update-manager-core
- Edit the config file

  > $ sudo vi /etc/update-manager/release-upgrades

  ...by changing this line

  set Prompt=normal;
- Launch the upgrade tool with the command

  > $ sudo do-release-upgrade -d

  ...and follow the on-screen instructions.